# How do I override a method in a subclass in Java?

Tags: java

First off, I need to override the method:

public boolean recordBid(int bidPrice, String sellerID)

so it manages the recording of a bid.

To begin with, if the bidPrice is greater than the buyNowprice then this bidPrice should reset to the buyNowPrice. After the bid price has been reset (if required) the method should invoke the superclass version of the recordBid() method, passing along the bid price and seller ID as parameters, and trap the result that it returns (ie. store it in a variable), so that it can be checked to determine if the bid price has been recorded successfully.

Im a little confused on how I need to trap the result and also not sure if Im doing it the right way here?.

My original recordBid() method:

```
public boolean recordBid(int bidPrice, String bidderID)
{
  if (saleEnded == true)
  {
     return false;
  }

  else if (bidPrice <= this.highestBid)
  {
     return false;
  }

  else
  {
     this.highestBid = bidPrice;
     this.bidderID = bidderID;
     return true;
  }
}
```

My subclass, where I need to overwrite recordBid()

```
public class BuyItNowSale extends ItemSale {


//instance variables
private double buyNowPrice;
private boolean acceptingNearestOffer;



public BuyItNowSale(String itemNumber, String itemDescription, String itemCondition,
        String sellerID, boolean acceptingNearestOffer) {


super(itemNumber, itemDescription, itemCondition, sellerID);

    this.acceptingNearestOffer = false;


//overidden recordBid() method

public boolean recordBid(int bidPrice, String bidderID)  {

    if(bidPrice > buyNowPrice) {

        bidPrice = 0;
        super.recordBid(bidPrice, sellerID);

    }



}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do; but based on your code sample, you might like to write it as `if(bidPrice > buyNowPrice) { bidPrice = 0; return super.recordBid(bidPrice, bidderID); } else { return false;}` - you need to use `return` statements to transmit the return value of the call to the superclass method back to the caller of the subclass method.

Comment: Your code isn't doing this "To begin with, if the bidPrice is greater than the buyNowprice then this bidPrice should reset to the buyNowPrice", it is setting the bid price to 0, instead of buyNowPrice.

Answer (score 0):

With your requirement

> if the bidPrice is greater than the buyNowprice then this bidPrice should reset to the buyNowPrice

Your method should be:

```
@Override
public boolean recordBid(int bidPrice, String bidderID)  {
    if(bidPrice > buyNowPrice) {
        bidPrice = (int) buyNowPrice;
    }
    return super.recordBid(bidPrice, sellerID);
}
```

Comment: this line :  bidPrice = buyNowPrice  is not working it says "cannot convert from double to int"

Comment: @JoshGomez okay, I edited my answer, just cast `double` to `int`. You should specify one data type for your money variable.

Comment: recordBid(int bidPrice, String bidderID) "only final is permitted" this line is also giving an error

Comment: @JoshGomez Do you still put `recordBid` method declaration inside constructor?

Comment: what do you mean? return super.. isn't working either

Comment: You are declaring method `recordBid` inside the `BuyItNowSale` constructor, it is not eligible.